# Alamofire Bool in POST request will be sent as 'true'

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire

I'm trying to send a Swift Bool in a POST request, however the server expects a number for this, but the request HTTP body shows that the bool was sent as 'true'.

I'm creating the parameters like this:

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "quantity": quantity, // Int
            "amount": totalAmount, // Double
            "use_credit": NSNumber(bool: useCredit) // Bool useCredit
        ]
```

The post request looks like this:

```
func postRequest(url: String, params: [String : AnyObject]?, headers: [String : String]?, completion: APICompletionHandler) {
        self.manager.request(.POST, baseURL.stringByAppendingString(url), parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                completion(json: JSON(data), error: nil)
            case .Failure(let error):
                completion(json: nil, error: error)
            }
        })
    }
```

When printing out the HTTP body of response in the console I get the following:

```
{\"use_credit\":true,\"amount\":15,\"quantity\":1,\"event_id\":30}
```

Comment: Can't you just `"use_credit": Int(useCredit)`?

Comment: if whatever you post the data reached as String, so in backend side tell to change the type cast

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't think that the server side should do a cast, I don't understand why Alamofire is changing it back to true, although I'm casting it to a number.

Comment: Obvious, but: are you sure that `useCredit` is `false` when you encode the params?